# Create a Cube in Blender from Python

Tags: python, scripting

I can't quite figure this out, so I am hoping someone can help.

In Python, I want to create an empty object, and add a Cube primitive to the object. After that I want to create a new material, and set the object to use the material.

```
# Create an empty object.
basic_cube = bpy.data.objects.new("Basic_Cube", None)

# Add the object into the scene.
bpyscene.objects.link(basic_cube)
bpyscene.objects.active = basic_cube
basic_cube.select = True

# Add a Cube primitive to the empty object.
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0))

basic_cube_mesh.update()
```

But this does not add the cube primitive to the object. It adds it directly to the scene.

Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

Comment: The Add New Object python script template, in the text editor, creates an operator "Add New Mesh" which adds a cube to the scene,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to create the object with an empty mesh first, as you cannot assign a mesh to an empty later.

Further: primitive_cube_add(...) is supposed to create an object, since it is the same operator called by Add->Mesh->Cube from the menu.

So you can use BMesh to create your cube later and assign it to the empty mesh:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

bpyscene = bpy.context.scene

# Create an empty mesh and the object.
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new('Basic_Cube')
basic_cube = bpy.data.objects.new("Basic_Cube", mesh)

# Add the object into the scene.
bpyscene.objects.link(basic_cube)
bpyscene.objects.active = basic_cube
basic_cube.select = True

# Construct the bmesh cube and assign it to the blender mesh.
bm = bmesh.new()
bmesh.ops.create_cube(bm, size=1.0)
bm.to_mesh(mesh)
bm.free()
```