# Create a UV Sphere / Object in Blender from Python

Tags: python, scripting, bmesh

Referencing to this code:
[Create a Cube in Blender from Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63546/create-a-cube-in-blender-from-python)

```
import bpy
import bmesh

bpyscene = bpy.context.scene

# Create an empty mesh and the object.
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new('Basic_Sphere')
basic_sphere = bpy.data.objects.new("Basic_Sphere", mesh)

# Add the object into the scene.
bpyscene.objects.link(basic_sphere)
bpyscene.objects.active = basic_sphere
basic_sphere.select = True

# Construct the bmesh cube and assign it to the blender mesh.
bm = bmesh.new()
bmesh.ops.create_uvsphere(bm) # How to set the arguments right?
bm.to_mesh(mesh)
bm.free()
```

Can someone explain how to set the arguments write for this function?

```
bmesh.ops.create_uvsphere(bm, u_segments, v_segments, diameter, matrix, calc_uvs)
```

I am new to bpy, bmesh and I am looking for some more explaination on how to set these arguments right. My goal is to generate a UV Sphere with Subdivision Surface modiefier and smooth ;). Someone can give me some further explainations on how to create a UV Sphere with the script? Thanks :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**EDIT**: Updated for 2.8x, for prior see [revision](https://blender.stackexchange.com/revisions/93305/2)

```
import bpy
import bmesh

# Create an empty mesh and the object.
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new('Basic_Sphere')
basic_sphere = bpy.data.objects.new("Basic_Sphere", mesh)

# Add the object into the scene.
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(basic_sphere)

# Select the newly created object
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = basic_sphere
basic_sphere.select_set(True)

# Construct the bmesh sphere and assign it to the blender mesh.
bm = bmesh.new()
bmesh.ops.create_uvsphere(bm, u_segments=32, v_segments=16, radius=1)
bm.to_mesh(mesh)
bm.free()

bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='SUBSURF')
bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()
```

In this case you need keyword arguments for all but the first, meaning you need to specify the argument name like `u_segments=`. The first argument is a positional argument, you only need to give the value `bm`. How do I know that? Because the [Blender API Documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.ops.html?highlight=create_uvsphere#bmesh.ops.create_uvsphere) is not very precise here, Blender told me in the Error message "bmesh operators expect a single BMesh positional argument, all other args must be keyword".

`u_segments` and `v_segments` control the initial subdivision of the mesh. `radius` is the sphere radius in local coordinate system (object transforation comes on top). `matrix` can be used if you want to shear, scale, rotate or move the sphere in one step. `calc_uvs` is about UV maps, but don't ask me what exactly.