# How to render an image through the text editor?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, camera, text-editor

Is it possible to render an image by calling the camera through a command with the text editor? I have a series of meshes that I want to upload into blender and take an picture one at a time. I want to upload the mesh, take a picture, delete the mesh and then upload the new mesh. I have my code to upload each mesh one at a time through a loop to create my mesh through faces and verts. I know the orientation and size that my meshes will be created. I have set up my lighting and camera angle that I want. I am using blender 2.82

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate of: [Rendering a cube as png file using Blender's Python API](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/120523/51286).
(I would put this in a comment if I had enough reputation.)

The above answer includes the following, with the assumption your camera is already set up (note that I have not tested the code):

> Set the render settings of the current scene, and render it. write_still is necessary if you want the result to be written to the filepath. There will be no visual feedback during the render process.

```
# render settings
scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'PNG'
scene.render.filepath = "F:/image.png"
bpy.ops.render.render(write_still = 1)
```