# How to make cube?

Tags: mesh, objects

How do you make a cube in Blender?

Comment: This is really strange that this question is never asked here before! :p

Comment: Given the username possibly related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63546/create-a-cube-in-blender-from-python

Comment: Tempted to answer.. reinstall Blender,double-click on its icon...

Comment: @RobinBetts ... if "Add Cube" is the answer I'm asking and answering  how to make Plane, Sphere, Cone, Cylinder, Suzanne etc.

Comment: Ya know, this has a 1000 views, I wonder why.

Comment: what a weird question :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to take efforts to make it, there's an inbuilt option in Blender to add!
Just press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, then *Mesh*>*Cube*.
[image]

Also the Default Blender Startup file adds a cube automatically to the viewport!

Comment: No but with the programming

Comment: Like how to program a cube

Comment: @Programmer so you should follow the comment given by batFinger , and you shouldn't tick my answer as best answer, because it is not, and also in future, make your question detailed! ;)

Comment: No @Yash you told me how to make a cube manually i didn't know that either.\

Comment: @Programmer As you think :)